# Excel Convert one set of numbers to another

Tags: excel, vba

For my schools sports day i need to convert the position someone comes in to a score.

I need 2 kinds a competition of 4 people and of 8 people

so:

Place -> Score

```
1st->8,
2nd->7,
3rd->6,
...,
8th->1
```

and

```
1st->8,
2nd->6,
3rd->4,
4th->2
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: The place just comes out as 1,2,3,...,8 or 1,2,3,4 not 1st,2nd ect.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If we know that, then we are in a better position to assist you.

Comment: Honestly nothing I have no idea how to approach this

Comment: Full marks for honesty, but in general, Stack Overflow expects some effort before correcting or improving solutions. At present, your question is too broad, effectively saying, "will someone write the code for me.". However, consider sorting the results, and then using a for loop against the ordered items.

Comment: I'm sorry but I need this done (in excel and i'm fairly sure there are no loops in excel) and I don't know anything so before I let anyone down by wasting time messing it up myself I ask for help because I have NO IDEA what I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood, simply you can do something like this,

B1 -> `=IF(A2>8,"NA",9-A2)`
C1 -> `=IF(A2>4,"NA",10-2*A2)`

Once you enter the place in A1, you will get the score accordingly as below.[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks I'll try during lunch

Comment: This works thank you so much

Comment: Good to hear that it worked for you. Pls accept the answer, that will help others.

Comment: sorry never done this before